# Font displayed on screen is inverted

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts

So I have this project here which is a basic asteroids clone. The text in the upper left corner is inverted:

[image]

I want to know how to flip it so it is the correct way up. Now I believe I need to just scale the Y by -1 but I can't seem to figure out how to actually implement it in code and I've searched everywhere but can't apply any of the searches to my particular scenario. Here's the code that renders the text

```
void cFont::printText(LPCSTR text, FTPoint textPos)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(0.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f);
    theFont->Render(text, -1, textPos);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

and here's the code in main.cpp that calls this function

```
theFontMgr->getFont("Space")->printText("Asteriods", FTPoint(0.0f, -1, 0.0f));
```

I understand the issue but don't know how to fix it through code, I just don't know what to type.

Comment: you should be able to paste your image to imgur.com or something and then just add a link to the image

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fUUWapv.png      

Here's the link to it.

Comment: As you have not pasted the relevant code, I'd say "just fix your texture coordinates".

Comment: And what library is being used for "TheFontMgr"? Because the error is in /that/ code, not yours.

Comment: TheFontMgr is just it's own class. I figured it out anyway. I just have to scale the text by -1 in the printText method and then re position it.